# If I like a friend's old post, would my 'Like' appear to our friend's (mutual) news feed?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy, facebook-like

If I like a friend's really old post (2011 - something he posted to me - it actually appeared to me on my "ON THIS DAY" section) would my 'Like' appear on our mutual friend's news feed?

I don't want our mutual friend to know I still miss this other friend and his lovely post to me. But I kinda want this friend to remember it in a subtle way.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

If you like a post from the past, it will show up in yours and your mutual friends feed as well.

Also, he will get a notification for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it was posted by him/her on your Timeline, then your like will not appear on your friends's News Feed even not on mutual, but the person who posted will get a notification of your action. But if it was a post by him/her on their Timeline (you were mentioned in that post or not, that doesn't matter), then your action (Like, Reaction, Comment) will appear on your friends's News Feed and poster will get a notification.